# Cassandra : cant see any progress with the insertion of data

Tags: cassandra

Am newbie to cassandra.
My process workers are trying to insert into the cassandra db. After some few hours I cant see any progress of insertion.

My debug logs are saying the below across nodes of cassandra:

> WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-48] 2016-10-07 00:59:04,025
>   BatchStatement.java:287 - Batch of prepared statements for
>   [my_database.my_table] is of size 14264, exceeding specified threshold
>   of 5120 by 9144. WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2016-10-07 00:59:04,025
>   BatchStatement.java:287 - Batch of prepared statements for
>   [my_database.my_table] is of size 14272, exceeding specified threshold
>   of 5120 by 9152. WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-62] 2016-10-07 00:59:04,025
>   BatchStatement.java:287 - Batch of prepared statements for
>   [my_database.my_table] is of size 14304, exceeding specified threshold
>   of 5120 by 9184. WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-56] 2016-10-07 00:59:04,026
>   BatchStatement.java:287 - Batch of prepared statements for
>   [my_database.my_table] is of size 14240, exceeding specified threshold
>   of 5120 by 9120.
>
> DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2016-10-07 07:43:38,765 FailureDetector.java:456
>   - Ignoring interval time of 2710773843 for /10.157.47.131 DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2016-10-07 07:43:38,766 FailureDetector.java:456 -
>   Ignoring interval time of 2000307543 for /10.157.41.234 DEBUG
>   [GossipStage:1] 2016-10-07 07:43:57,769 FailureDetector.java:456 -
>   Ignoring interval time of 2069384918 for /10.157.43.166 DEBUG
>   [GossipStage:1] 2016-10-07 07:44:07,702 FailureDetector.java:456 -
>   Ignoring interval time of 2000430166 for /10.157.43.166 DEBUG
>   [GossipStage:1] 2016-10-07 07:44:14,772 FailureDetector.java:456 -
>   Ignoring interval time of 2000475716 for /10.157.43.166 DEBUG
>   [GossipStage:1] 2016-10-07 07:44:15,772 FailureDetector.java:456 -
>   Ignoring interval time of 2000349080 for /10.157.41.234 DEBUG
>   [GossipStage:1] 2016-10-07 07:44:17,773 FailureDetector.java:456 -
>   Ignoring interval time of 2000373755 for /10.157.43.166

Is this is the cause of concern. Any help/information/solution would be helpful

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

A batch is used in Cassandra to "bundle" related operations in a single execution, similar to a explicit transaction in a relational database.

If what you want is to upload large volumes of data into Cassandra, you can use [Bulk loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html), external tools like [Sqoop](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaSqpTOC.html), or asynchronous prepared statements.